# Powershell Stop-process with spaces in name, non exe extension

Tags: windows, powershell, portable-apps

In powershell how can I stop a process that has .dat extension and spaces in name

In task manager I see process name: "my portable app.dat"

Stop-process -processname my portable app (doesn't work)

adding quotes to name and adding extension doesn't help

Answer (score 2):

you can try

```
taskkill /f /t /im "my portable app.dat"
```

or append `.exe` to `.dat`

Answer (score 0):

Adding quotes and extension works if it is run as a .ps1 script

Stop-Process -processname "my portable app.dat"

I was trying the command in the command line tool (quotes don't seem to work there)

Comment: `stop-process` doesn't require extension (and will not work if provided)